# Polish letters in preg_match (php)

Tags: php, html

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-z_-]/", $var) == 1) { ... }
```

I would like to add Polish letters to this condition `ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż, z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[^\p{L}_-]` to find Polish letters